# Rails Admin Model with all upcase module name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, rails-admin

I have a model that is within an all upcase module :

```
# app/models/abc/site.rb
module ABC
  class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

And in config :

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
config.included_models = [
  'ABC::Site',
]

config.model ABC::Site do
  edit do
    ...
  end
end
```

But rails admin has links to the view that are lower case `/admin/abc~site`, and result in `Model 'Abc::Site' could not be found` being shown on the main index when clicked on.

We found that `/admin/ABC~site` does work, but any action on that page causes it to reload the lower case version.

I assume I have configured it incorrectly, does anyone know what I need to set?

- Rails 4.2.4
- rails_admin (0.8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried declaring it as an acronym in an initializer?

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.acronym 'ABC'
end
```

Comment: Bingo! The URL does not update the case, which of course doesn't matter, but the model lookup works! Thanks!